How to avoid deadlocks with the EntityManager.merge method in JPA (Java Persistence API)?
I am using the EntityManager from javax.persistence in my Spring application, and I am encountering issues with deadlocks when calling the merge method.
Here's my understanding of the internal workings of EntityManager.merge():
When merge is called, there is an internal SELECT query executed by the ID of the given entity.
The retrieved data is then changed, and finally, an UPDATE statement is executed.
This process is controlled by the @Transactional annotation in Spring.
The problem I am facing is that these internal SELECT queries initiated by the merge method are causing deadlocks in my database. To avoid this, I want to add a NOLOCK hint to the SELECT query. However, I understand that it is not possible to directly modify this internal SELECT query since it is generated by the merge method.
Here are my questions:
Is there a way to modify the behavior of the internal SELECT query generated by EntityManager.merge() to include a NOLOCK hint?
If not, what are some recommended strategies or best practices to avoid deadlocks when using EntityManager.merge() in a high-concurrency environment?
Any insights or alternative approaches to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
If you need additional context, here is a sample of how the merge method is typically used in my code:
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public MyEntity updateMyEntity(MyEntity entity) {
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}


Do you know which tables are involved in the deadlock? And then why do you get deadlocks? Are you updating concurrently the same rows?

One table is involved in the deadlock.  In the first login in my application, a row is inserted using entityManager.persist. Then, during 2FA, the same row is retrieved using a SELECT query by a named query of the entity manager. After that, a merge call is initiated by changing some values in that row. After 2FA, the token service accesses the same row with a SELECT query and adds a new token to the row with another merge. This is the flow of my application. Each user has a unique row, and no one else accesses it. In my application, a large number of users try to log in using this service.

So that means that you have two process on the same row?

If you have SELECT and UPDATE statement on the same row then it is always deadlocked. For this kind of execution there's SELECT FOR UPDATE statement that takes an exclusive lock on the row which you want to modify. Other threads can't retake it until you release the lock.

Actually, I am not performing the SELECT and UPDATE concurrently. After the SELECT, I do some processing, and then at the end of the process, I call merge for an update. However, while running the application in debug mode, I observed that EntityManager.merge() internally initiates a SELECT call to check with the database. This SELECT was the reason for the deadlock. Do I need to replace the merge method of the EntityManager? For better control over the update.
